# cf-client returns more service instances than expected

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

I am trying to retrieve service instances from CF that belong to a specific ORG/SPACE combination. First I tried to add both with the filter query:

```
var serviceInstances = new cfClient.ServiceInstances(ENDPOINT);  
serviceInstances.getInstances(`q=space_guid:${SPACE_GUID}& organization_guid:${ORG_GUID}`);
```

..but it seems as if the combination of more than one filter condition is not allowed.

Second, I tried to filter for the space only because I assume that the GUID is unique (!!):

```
serviceInstances.getInstances(`q=space_guid:${SPACE_GUID}`)
```

...but in this case I am getting instances that belong to other spaces, too! But why?

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know about the language API you're using, but the standard CAPI has a different endpoint if you want to get the service instances under a space.  It's `/v2/spaces/<space-guid>/service_instances`.  http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/1.27.0/spaces/list_all_service_instances_for_the_space.html.  I'm sure you can do it in multiple ways, so not to say one way is right or wrong.  Just something to consider if your language binding supports it.

Comment: Also, filtering on org guid & space guid seems redundant.  Spaces can only live in one org, so if you filter on the space guid it should give you service instances filtered by the org & space.  If you do want to filter on multiple things, it should be possible.  Ex: `/v2/service_instances?q=space_guid:<space-guid>&q=name:<service-name>`.  Your example above is missing the second `q=` before `organization_guid`.

Comment: Agreed! But filtering still seems not to work pretty well. I tried passing `'q=name>"pommes"'` and `'q=name:"pommes*"'` to retrieve all instances starting with pommes but all instances are returned.

Comment: A couple things.  Don't put quotes around the name.  i.e. `q=name:pomes` not `q=name:"pomes"`.  I'm pretty sure it's going to include the quotes with the name, so unless the actual name has quotes in it, you don't want them.  Second.  There is no wildcard matching so `pomes*` is not going to do what you want.  It will match the literal string `pomes*`, not anything starting with `pomes`.  Using `name>pomes` isn't going to get you things starting with `pomes` either.  It will lexicographically compare strings and include those greater than what you enter.

Comment: If you need more advanced filtering, not available through the API, you'll need to do that client side.  If you're scripting, `jq` works very well to do that.  If you're using a programming language, then just use the features of that language to parse and filter the resulting JSON.